# Bash ending the variable after first space?

Tags: bash, sqlplus

I'm building a string in Bash in a loop. The data processed by the loop from the lines in two files which are looking like this:

FIRST part of the string is a line in file 1 looking like:

```
SOME_PACKAGE
```

SECOND PART is a line of a file 2 looking like:

```
someFunction('some',parameters,here)
```

The final output has a dot between the two strings:

```
1 SOME_PACKAGE.someFunction('some',parameters,here)
```

The **1** is important here. Explaination in a second.

The string is formed in a double `while` loop

```
while read line1 ; do
    while read line2 ; do
      stringArray=($line2)
      string=$line1.${stringArray[1]}

        sqlplus -s /nolog > /dev/null 2>&1  <<EOF
        connect user/password@db_instance
        variable rc refcursor;
        SPOOL ${line1}_${stringArray[0]}.DATA
        exec :rc := $string;
        print rc;
        spool off
        exit
        EOF

    done < file2.txt
done < file1.txt
```

This string is then passed to SQL*Plus, and SQL*Plus should exit a command like this:

```
SQL> variable rc refcursor;
SQL> exec :rc := SOME_PACKAGE.someFunction('some',parameters,here);
SQL> print rc;
```

Until now, everything was working fine. But I got a more complicated parameters next to the someFunction. Now it looks like this:

```
SOME_PACKAGE.someFunction('some',parameters,here,'and 2 more',NULL)
```

It seems that the variable passed to SQL*Plus ends on the first space... So it looks like:

```
SOME_PACKAGE.someFunction('some',parameters,here,'and
```

From what I know I shouldnt pass spaces in variables, or if I want to do this, I should wrap them in quote signs: `""` but where should I put those quote signs to pass the final vatiable to SQL*Plus WITHOUT those quote signs? Or what other solution do You guys propose?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your field separator. What if you set `IFS=` in the nested while loop?

Comment: @arco444, truly, the question I asked is formed wrongly, cause I've ommited a very important fact, that I thought it was not important at all... Let me update the question.

Comment: @arco444 now the question is complete, but I think that `IFS` could be the answer to my troubles...

Answer (score 2):

The answer was simple thanks to @arco444.

The reason all this happened was the Internal field separator, which was set to default.

What I did was the following:

I've changed the look of `file2` from

```
1 SOME_PACKAGE.someFunction('some',parameters,here,'and 2 more',NULL)
```

to

```
1§SOME_PACKAGE.someFunction('some',parameters,here,'and 2 more',NULL)
```

And I added some `ILS` changes before and after the loop, so the final code looks like this:

```
oldifs=$IFS
IFS="§"

while read line1 ; do
    while read line2 ; do
      stringArray=($line2)
      string=$line1.${stringArray[1]}

        sqlplus -s /nolog > /dev/null 2>&1  <<EOF
        connect user/password@db_instance
        variable rc refcursor;
        SPOOL ${line1}_${stringArray[0]}.DATA
        exec :rc := $string;
        print rc;
        spool off
        exit
        EOF

    done < file2.txt
done < file1.txt

IFS=$oldifs
```

Everything is working like a charm now.